# SHA1 - Convert C#/ASP.Net Function to PHP SHA1

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, encryption, sha1

Plesae help me to convert the C# / ASP  SHA1 Function given below to compatible PHP SHA1 function

```
public string SHA1(string data)
{
    byte[] hash = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(
                         new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(data));
    string str = string.Empty;
    foreach (byte num in hash)
       str = str + string.Format("{0,0:x2}", (object) num);
    return str;
}
```

I want the above SHA1 function in PHP which can return the same value in PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Put your codes between { and }. And put your input and output.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a builtin sha1() function which performs all of these steps and provides hexidecimal output.  It should be compatible, although you'd have to be sure the string encoding and padding were handled exactly the same way in both languages, or you'll get different hash outputs.

```
$str = 'apple';

if (sha1($str) === 'd0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940') {
    echo "Would you like a green or red apple?";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff for answering quickly but as I am newbie, I dont know what string encoding is used in C# code mentioned above in my question. 

public string SHA1(string source)
  {
    byte[] hash = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(source));
    string str = string.Empty;
    foreach (byte num in hash)
      str = str + string.Format("{0,0:x2}", (object) num);
    return str;
  }

Comment: It looks like the C# is UTF8 encoding the data, UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(source) before calling the ComputeHash() function, so you have to make sure the PHP string is also utf8 encoded.  If it's not, you can convert it to UTF8 with the PHP function utf8_encode(string).

Comment: @Jeff-InventorChromeOS help me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865164/migrating-old-net-application-to-new-php-application-getting-issue-while-imple