# Migrating old .net application to new php application: getting issue while implementing password encrypt/decrypt with sha1 alogorithm

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

**Migrating old .net application to new php application: getting issue while implementing password encrypt/decrypt with sha1 alogorithm**

As I mentioned, I am trying to implement password encryption and decryption (in new php app) while registration and login flows. I am using sha1() php function for password encrypt and decrypt. I have to implement sha1 functionality through which old app (.net app, with sha1 algorithm) users should also get new php app login **with old passwords**.

My php sha1 code during login:

```
..
..
$user_pass = $q->row('password'); //password stored in db (generated through .net sha1)
$inputPwd = utf8_decode(sha1($password, TRUE)); //password entered during login

if($inputPwd === $user_pass) {
     return $q->row();
}
..
..
```

**Issue that in above code snippet, both values are not matching.**

**If I register new user in php app. then he is getting login properly.**

```
Only not getting login to migrated users (from .net)
```

Getting minor differences in both passwords, one generated through .net sha1 algorithm 
and another one I am generating through php sha1 algorithm during login to match both passwords.

**getting little bit difference between them**

Getting Passwords Like:

**1) 7e???/?uH?}?QP&?e (php), 2) 7e???/?uH?}?QP&??e (.net)**

please suggest me any changes or ideas so that I can match php generated sha1 password with old .net sha1 generated password.. to get login properly.

**My PHP Version: 7.1**

Comment: Whats the type of the database column?
Because using uft8_decode on the binary sha1 result does not look like a good idea

Comment: password column is with data type: varchar(255) and collation: latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: what happens if you remove the utf8_decode?

Comment: It gives me password output but it includes question marks like "�" it causes password mismatch.. thats why I am using utf8_decode()

Comment: @Bernhard if you've any idea then plz suggest me

Comment: I think you have problems because your database is latin1
try 
mb_convert_encoding(sha1($password, TRUE), 'latin1');

Comment: sry.. but its giving totally different value (like "{pZ]x^")